# Testing core.async code in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

I'm trying to test some core.async code, but I'm having trouble writing tests. All of my test code is in a `go` block, but it seems like the process my test is on isn't parked in the way I expected it to be.

After I do the put on the `actions` channel, I would expect execution of the `go` block to be parked until the value is taken, but instead the `is` function runs straight away which causes my test to fail because the `state-atom` hasn’t been updated yet.

Here's my test code:

```
(deftest tab-change
  (async done
         (go (>! state/actions (state/TabChange. :return))
             (is (= @state/state-atom {:tab :return}))
             (done))))
```

And the code under test:

```
(def actions (async/chan))

(declare update)

(def state-atom (reagent/atom nil))

(go-loop []
  (swap! state-atom (partial update (<! actions)))
  (recur))

(defprotocol Action
  (update [action state]))

(defrecord TabChange [value]
  Action
  (update [_ state]
    (assoc state :tab value)))
```

If I change my test code to use `put!` and a callback, rather than a `go` block, the tests pass:

```
(deftest tab-change
  (async done
         (put! state/actions
               (state/TabChange. :return)
               #(do (is (= @state/state-atom {:tab :return}))
                    (done)))))
```

This obviously won't compose well for more complicated tests though, so I was hoping for some insight into what is causing the problem with the original test.

Comment: "> but it seems like the process my test is on isn't parked in the way I expected it to be.” Can you explain this further?

Comment: I’ve added a paragraph further explaining the behaviour I’m seeing. Is it clearer now?