# Testing with core.async - flushing go blocks inside a test?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async, reagent

I am trying to write a test like this:

```
(deftest login-form-rendering
  (async done (with-redefs [http/post fake-login-success]
        (with-mounted-component (c/login-form login!)
          (fn [c div]
            (.click (.getElementById js/document "Login"))
            (is (= (:page @app-state) :location)))))
         (done)))
```

I have this mock:

```
(defn fake-login-success [& _]
  (let [ch (chan)
        response {:status 200}]
    (go (>! ch response)
        ch)))
```

The login function does this:

```
(defn login! [username password]
  (go (let [result (->> {:form-params {:username @username :password @password}}
                        (http/post "/api/login")
                        (<!))
            {status :status body :body} result]
        (case status
          401 (swap! app-state assoc :page :bad-login)
          200 (swap! app-state assoc :page :location)))))
```

The login form is a reagent component that takes a callback for onClick. app-state is a globally accessible atom.

The problem I'm facing is that the go block inside login! is never executed. Is there something I need to do to flush the channel or something?

I see there is also this unanswered question that's similar: [Testing core.async code in ClojureScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273545/testing-core-async-code-in-clojurescript). One difference seems to be that I don't have an explicit channel in my code under test. That's being generated by the cljs-http post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is a misplaced parenthesis.

```
(let [ch (chan)
      response {:status 200}]
    (go (>! ch response)
        ch))
```

The return value of this `let` is the `go` block's channel. It is a channel containing nothing, since:

1. The `go` block is trying to put on an unbuffered channel, requiring some other operation to "meet" it and do the complementary take in order for its own execution to proceed.
2. `ch` is lexically hidden from the outside world, so no operation can exist which can perform the complementary take.

If something somehow did take from it (or we added a buffer to `ch` so the first put succeeds), `ch` would be put on the returned channel.

```
(let [ch (chan)
      response {:status 200}]
    (go (>! ch response))
    ch)
```

The return value of this `let` is `ch`, with no additional channel wrapping it. The `go`-block is parked trying to put on `ch` until something like your test gets around to taking from it.

However, since we're ultimately just looking to construct a channel with a constant on it, `go` itself seems like the simplest solution:

```
(defn fake-login-success [& _]
  (go {:status 200})
```